# How can insert or append to inserting string in existing string

Tags: c#, string, append

ı want to add another string to the end of an existing string.

for example
`string before = "00000"; string add = "175"; string last = "000175";` 
I want to make like 'last' type.

I am trying below

`var last = before.Remove(1, before.Length).Insert(before.Length,add );`

Comment: Do you want to add it to the end? Then last should be "00000175". Or do you want to replace the last three characters to "00175"? The description you make is not the same as the expected result you put there.

Comment: You can't change a string that easily you always create a new string. Strings can be simply concatenated `last = before + add`. But i doubt that what you ask is what you want. Your code implies something different. Please update the question and be more clear of the result you want to have.

Comment: Thank you sir,I want to do replace the last three characters to "00175".actually i always want to append to the end of existing string.

Comment: As I see your actual question is how to prepend or prepad a number with zero's to a desired length?

Comment: What research have you done so far? If you look in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-7.0) can you find anything that lets you select a smaller part of a string, i.e. substring? Or to merge two strings, i.e. concatenation?